# setting upper and lower limits in rnorm

Tags: r

I am simulating data using rnorm, but I need to set an upper and lower limit, does anyone know how to do this?

code:

```
rnorm(n = 10, mean = 39.74, sd = 25.09)
```

Upper limit needs to be 340, and the lower limit 0

I am asking this question because I am rewriting an SAS-code into an R-code. I have never used SAS.
I am trying to rewrite the following piece of code:

```
sim_sample(simtot=100000,seed=10004,lbound=0,ubound=340,round_y=0.01,round_m=0.01,round_sd=0.01,n=15,m=39.74,sd=25.11,mk=4)
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do. The normal distribution is unlimited by definition. Do you want a different distribution (e.g., `runif` that lets you define limits) or discard values outside of you limits? Please clarify.

Comment: I want to sample data from a normal distribution, but with limits on the range. In this case, I have a mean of 39.74 and a SD of 25.09, and I need to sample data with this mean and standard deviation, but the numbers cannoot exceed 340. Do I need to use runif for this?

Comment: You don't seem to know what you need. That makes it hard to answer your question.

Comment: I do know what I need, I just don't know how to get it. I have a SAS code that I am trying to rewrite in R, and in that SAS code the writer has an upper and a lower limit while sampling with a certain mean and standard deviation. Is sample() an option?

I have put the SAS code that I am trying to rewrite in the question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Like this?

```
mysamp <- function(n, m, s, lwr, upr, nnorm) {
  samp <- rnorm(nnorm, m, s)
  samp <- samp[samp >= lwr & samp <= upr]
  if (length(samp) >= n) {
    return(sample(samp, n))
  }  
  stop(simpleError("Not enough values to sample from. Try increasing nnorm."))
}

set.seed(42)
mysamp(n=10, m=39.74, s=25.09, lwr=0, upr=340, nnorm=1000)
#[1] 58.90437 38.72318 19.64453 20.24153 39.41130 12.80199 59.88558 30.88578 19.66092 32.46025
```

However, the result is **not** normal distributed and usually won't have the mean and sd you've specified (in particular if the limits are not symmetric around the specified mean).

### Edit:

According to your comment it seems you want to translate [this SAS function](http://opim.wharton.upenn.edu/%7Euws/data/JustPostIt/SAS%20Code/macros/sim_sample.sas). I am not an SAS user, but this should do more or less the same:

```
mysamp <- function(n, m, s, lwr, upr, rounding) {
  samp <- round(rnorm(n, m, s), rounding)
  samp[samp < lwr] <- lwr
  samp[samp > upr] <- upr
  samp
}

set.seed(8)
mysamp(n=10, m=39.74, s=25.09, lwr=0, upr=340, rounding=3)
#[1] 37.618 60.826 28.111 25.920 58.207 37.033 35.467 12.434  0.000 24.857
```

You may then want to use `replicate` to run the simulations. Or if you want faster code:

```
sim <- matrix(mysamp(n=10*10, m=39.74, s=25.09, lwr=0, upr=340, rounding=3), 10)
means <- colMeans(sim)
sds <- apply(sim, 2, sd)
```

Answer (score 32):

The rtruncnorm() function will return the results you need.

```
  library(truncnorm)
  rtruncnorm(n=10, a=0, b=340, mean=39.4, sd=25.09)
```

Answer (score 15):

You can make your own truncated normal sampler that doesn't require you to throw out observations quite simply

```
rtnorm <- function(n, mean, sd, a = -Inf, b = Inf){
    qnorm(runif(n, pnorm(a, mean, sd), pnorm(b, mean, sd)), mean, sd)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want exactly 10 numbers and not the subset of them that is >0, <340 (and night not be a normal distribution):

```
    aa <- rnorm(n = 10, mean = 39.74, s = 25.09)

    while(any(aa<0 | aa>340)) { aa <- rnorm(n = 10, mean = 39.74, s = 25.09) }
```

Comment: Depending on n and the limits set this function could take a *very* long time to generate the sample of interest

Answer (score 0):

This is the function that I wrote to achieve the same purpose. It normalizes the result from the `rnorm` function and then adjusts it to fit the range.

**NOTE:** The standard deviation and mean (if specified) get altered during the normalization process.

```
#' Creates a random normal distribution within the specified bounds.
#' 
#' WARNING: This function does not preserve the standard deviation or mean.
#' @param n The number of values to be generated
#' @param mean The mean of the distribution
#' @param sd The standard deviation of the distribution
#' @param lower The lower limit of the distribution
#' @param upper The upper limit of the distribution
rtnorm <- function(n, mean=NA, sd=1, lower=-1, upper=1){
  mean = ifelse(is.na(mean)|| mean < lower || mean > upper,
                mean(c(lower, upper)), mean)
  data <- rnorm(n, mean=m, sd=sd) # data

  if (!is.na(lower) && !is.na(upper)){ # adjust data to specified range
    drange <- range(data)           # data range
    irange <- range(lower, upper)   # input range
    data <- (data - drange[1])/(drange[2] - drange[1]) # normalize data (make it 0 to 1)
    data <- (data * (irange[2] - irange[1]))+irange[1] # adjust to specified range
  }
  return(data)
}
```

Comment: Note that this isn't the same as what is typically referred to as a truncated normal.

Comment: @Dason: No, it is not a truncated normal distribution. It rather expands/reduces the bounds of a standard normal distribution to meet the specified upper and lower limits.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to set upper and lower limits to a *normal distribution*, what will cause that the result is *no* longer *normal distributed*.

Assuming a `mean=0`, `sd=1` producing `N=1e5` values with a lower boundary of `LO=-1` and an upper boundary of `UP=2`.

```
N <- 1e5L
LO <- -1
UP <- 2
```

Move outliers to border (@Roland)

```
set.seed(42)
x <- pmax(LO, pmin(UP, rnorm(N)))
mean(x)
#[1] 0.07238029
median(x)
#[1] -0.002066374
sd(x)
#[1] 0.8457605
hist(x, 30)
```

[image: hist of Set outliers to borders]

Cut outliers of (@Dason, @Roland, truncnorm::rtruncnorm, MCMCglmm::rtnorm)

```
set.seed(42)
x <- qnorm(runif(N, pnorm(LO), pnorm(UP)))
mean(x)
#[1] 0.2317875
median(x)
#[1] 0.173679
sd(x)
#[1] 0.7236536
```

[image: hist of Cut outliers of]

Scale (@Alex Essilfie)

```
set.seed(42)
x <- rnorm(N)
x <- (x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x))*(UP-LO)+LO
mean(x)
#[1] 0.4474876
median(x)
#[1] 0.4482257
sd(x)
#[1] 0.3595199
```

[image: hist of scale]

Combination of methods. E.g. Cut and scale:

```
set.seed(42)
x <- qnorm(runif(N, pnorm(-3), pnorm(3)))
x <- (x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x))*(UP-LO)+LO
mean(x)
#[1] 0.5010759
median(x)
#[1] 0.5014713
sd(x)
#[1] 0.4957751
```

[image: hist of Combination]

Asymmetric combination

```
set.seed(42)
n <- round(N*abs(LO)/diff(range(c(LO, UP))))
x <- c(qnorm(runif(n, pnorm(-3), 0.5)), qnorm(runif(N-n, 0.5, pnorm(3))))
x <- ifelse(x < 0, x/min(x)*LO, x/max(x)*UP)
mean(x)
#[1] 0.2651627
median(x)
#[1] 0.2127903
sd(x)
#[1] 0.5078264
```

[image: hist of asymmetric combination]